# Eager loading relationship from an Enum casted column returns error

Tags: laravel, enums, eager-loading

I created **RoleEnum** and cast it in User model. The role_id which is being cast to RoleEnum also has relationship to Role model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Enums;

enum RoleEnum:int
{
    case SYSTEM_ADMINISTRATOR = 1;
    case ADMINISTRATOR = 2;
    case SAMPLE_ROLE_ONE = 3;
    case SAMPLE_ROLE_TWO = 4;
    case SAMPLE_ROLE_THREE = 5;
    case SAMPLE_ROLE_FOUR = 6;
}
```

**User Model**

```
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    'password' => 'hashed',
    'role_id' => RoleEnum::class,
];

public function role(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

And in my **controller index**

```
$users = User::with('role')
    ->paginate()
    ->withQueryString();
```

And I'm getting this error and it is pointing in **paginate()**. It must be using the class instead of the value.

```
Object of class App\Enums\RoleEnum could not be converted to string
```

**Edit:** After further testing, I found out that the error is caused by eager loading the role which is an Enum casted column and not by paginate(). I can simply remove the Enum casting and everything will work fine. But is there a way to cast an Enum and still use eager loading?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a Role table with the fields id, name, slug, level
The migration should look like this

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger('level');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

and the users table

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger('role_id')->index();
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

you are free to personalize everything

Then, the relationships on the models must be managed depending on what you want, in these examples a user only has one role and I put the level field in order to be able to prioritize your roles later.

In the Role model, place these lines

```
public function users(){
     return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

In the User model, place these lines

```
public function role(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

Then you can do

```
$users = User::with('role')
     ->paginate(10)
     ->withQueryString();
```

Comment: I already have a roles table and each user can only have one role. The problem lies in eager loading the role while casting the role_id as an Enum.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create a role that changes dynamically? Yes, why not modify the user although that will bombard your site with useless queries.

Comment: No. I already have that feature. The goal is, to cast role_id as Enum while using eager loading. Eager loading seems to return instance of RoleEnum instead of the values. I have updated my title and added my findings in the question.